Efficiently sort the k lowest elements of a numpy array while excluding some indices using argpartition
I am trying to implement the most efficient way to sort only k elements of an array, while excluding some ones from the sorting. Currently, I am using the following function that takes advantage of numpy argpartition:
def find_cads_indices_closest_to_target_distance(
    cad_idx,
    embeddings,
    target_distance,
    closest_to_target_distance_count=1,
    excluded_indices=None,
    metric="cosine",
):
    # Include cad_idx in excluded_indices by default
    if excluded_indices is None:
        excluded_indices = [cad_idx]
    elif cad_idx not in excluded_indices:
        excluded_indices.append(cad_idx)

    reference_embedding = embeddings[cad_idx]
    # Compute distances based on the specified metric
    if metric == "cosine":
        distances = cosine_distances([reference_embedding], embeddings)[0]
    elif metric == "euclidean":
        distances = euclidean_distances([reference_embedding], embeddings)[0]
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid metric. Choose 'cosine' or 'euclidean'.")

    differences = np.abs(distances - target_distance)

    # Find indices of the embeddings with the smallest differences
    indices_of_closest_to_target = np.argpartition(
        differences, closest_to_target_distance_count + len(excluded_indices)
    )[: closest_to_target_distance_count + len(excluded_indices)]

    # Exclude the indices in excluded_indices from the list
    indices_of_closest_to_target = [
        idx for idx in indices_of_closest_to_target if idx not in excluded_indices
    ]

    # If there are more than samples_count indices, trim the list
    indices_of_closest_to_target = indices_of_closest_to_target[
        :closest_to_target_distance_count
    ]

    # Optional, sort indices by distance
    indices_of_closest_to_target = sorted(
        indices_of_closest_to_target, key=lambda idx: differences[idx]
    )

    # Return the cads corresponding to the closest embeddings and the distances to them
    return (
        indices_of_closest_to_target,
        distances[indices_of_closest_to_target],
    )

I am not happy with it because it sort more elements that needed. I have tried unsuccessfully to natively ignore the indices during the sort. If you can help me, by using some intricacies of argpartition, or another way around, I take !
Thanks !

How about partition to identify the block that needs further sorting.  And then argsort to do a sort on that part?

When you trim the list of indexes, is there a risk that some excluded indexes point to distances that are smaller than some of the included distances, because "The order of all elements in the partitions is undefined" according to argpartition documentation.

"most efficient" way might depend on the size of your array, and the number of indexes you want to exclude.

@Indeed TMBailey I had not thought about it…. I work with fairly large arrays (length 100000) and the number of excluded indices never exceeds 4.

A first easy fix to the trim would be to invert the two last operations. I will also have a look at the proposal of @hpaulj this afternoon

I had also come up with a solution
# Exclude the indices in excluded_indices from the differences array     max_value = np.max(differences) + 1     for idx in excluded_indices:         differences[idx] = max_value 
This workaround avoids to use the trim trick, but i do not know if it is as efficient as a version that directly ignores the indices.

To determine whether one specific solution is more efficient (faster) than another, you can time how long it takes to run on some test data--see https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/timeit.html .  There are many examples in StackOverflow and elsewhere.

yes, I am doing it right now and i come back to you when it s done ! thanks !

It depends.  There may be trade-offs between the amount of space used and the amount of processing time, and the trade-offs may depend on the size of your data, the value of k, and the number of items you want to exclude.
Either way, you can get argpartition to do the sorting by passing it range(k) instead of just passing k.
If k is relatively small, and the number of items to exclude is small, you might want to avoid making copies of a big data array, and sorting a few extra items maybe does not matter much.  In that case, you could try something like this:
def best_k_simple(data, k=1, exclude=[]):
    k_plus_excludes = k + len(exclude)
    # Get best k_plus_excludes indexes, in sorted order.
    best_indexes_sorted = np.argpartition(data, range(k_plus_excludes))
    # Drop excluded indexes if in best.
    best_indexes_sorted = [i for i in best_indexes_sorted if i not in exclude]
    # Trim to just k best indexes.
    best_indexes_sorted = best_indexes_sorted[:k]
    return (best_indexes_sorted, data[best_indexes_sorted])

Demo
import numpy as np

# Define toy data.
data = np.arange(8, 0, -1)
# array([8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1])

# Get best 3, ignoring items 2 and 6 (data values 6 and 2).
best_k_simple(data, k=3, exclude=[2, 6])
# ([7, 5, 4], array([1, 3, 4]))

If you really want to avoid sorting items that are going to be excluded, you probably have to make a copy of the data that leaves out the items to be excluded, like this:
def best_k_limited_sorting(data, k=1, exclude=[]):
    data_indexes = range(len(data))
    included_indexes = np.array(list(set(data_indexes) - set(exclude)))
    data_included = data[included_indexes]
    # Get best k indexes in data_included, in sorted order.
    best_indexes = np.argpartition(data_included, range(k))[:k]
    # Map to indexes in original data.
    best_data_indexes = included_indexes[best_indexes]
    return (best_data_indexes, data[best_data_indexes])

Demo
# Get best 3, ignoring items 2 and 6 (data values 6 and 2).
best_k_limited_sorting(data, k=3, exclude=[2, 6])
# (array([7, 5, 4]), array([1, 3, 4]))


@accoumar I think the returned indices do correspond to the original indices, unless I am missing something.  Can you find an example where they do not?

sorry i was too quick you are right, Thanks !

I finally came up with this solution:
def find_cads_indices_closest_to_target_distance(
    cad_idx,
    embeddings,
    target_distance,
    closest_to_target_distance_count=1,
    excluded_indices=None,
    metric="cosine",
):
    # Include cad_idx in excluded_indices by default, because we do not want to select it as a closest cad...
    if excluded_indices is None:
        excluded_indices = [cad_idx]
    elif cad_idx not in excluded_indices:
        excluded_indices.append(cad_idx)

    reference_embedding = embeddings[cad_idx]
    if metric == "cosine":
        distances = cosine_distances([reference_embedding], embeddings)[0]
    elif metric == "euclidean":
        distances = euclidean_distances([reference_embedding], embeddings)[0]
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid metric. Choose 'cosine' or 'euclidean'.")

    differences = np.abs(distances - target_distance)

    # Exclude the indices in excluded_indices from the differences array, by setting their value to a high value not to be selected
    for idx in excluded_indices:
        differences[idx] = np.inf

    # Find indices of the embeddings with the smallest differences, the range is needed here to get the selected indices in the correct order !
    indices_of_closest_to_target = np.argpartition(
        differences, range(closest_to_target_distance_count)
    )[:closest_to_target_distance_count]

    return (
        indices_of_closest_to_target,
        distances[indices_of_closest_to_target],
    )

This turns out to be the fastest version I've tried, when working with an array of size ~50000 and when excluding only 2 indices. The improvements in time are marginal, due to the fact that i only exclude 2 indices. The real improvement comes from the use of the range() inside the argpartition, that allows to get the indices in an 'ordered' way.
Thanks for your help.
